# How to make a Group by and order by max(...) in django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql-9.3

I want to get the last category in a table of publications.
This is the correct SQL code:

```
select id_categoria_id, max(update_time) from showgroups_publicacion group by id_categoria_id order by max(update_time) desc
```

> 1 |   "2015-05-04 18:25:19-04" 
>  5    |   "2015-05-04 18:25:15-04" 
>   0 |   "2015-05-04 18:24:35-04" 
>  2    |   "2015-05-04 18:12:13-04"

In django I have this:

```
cat_pub = Publicacion.objects.all().values('id_categoria').annotate(Max('update_time'))
```

cat_pub.query:

```
SELECT showgroups_publicacion.id_categoria_id, MAX(showgroups_publicacion.update_time) AS update_time__max FROM showgroups_publicacion GROUP BY showgroups_publicacion.id_categoria_id
```

> 0 |   "2015-05-04 18:24:35-04" 
>  1    |   "2015-05-04 18:25:19-04" 
>   2 |   "2015-05-04 18:12:13-04" 
>  5    |   "2015-05-04 18:25:15-04"

I want to make the order by max in django, how I can solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cat_pub = Publicacion.objects.all().values('id_categoria').annotate(max_update_time=Max('update_time')).order_by('-max_update_time')
```